# Parsing mp4 metadata

Tags: java, streaming, video-streaming, mp4, codec

I am faced with a problem. I have a mp4 file which has been run through mp4box. I run it with the interleaved option to generated metadata for the file. I can dump an XML file of the metadata which contains data like

```
<CompositionOffsetEntry CompositionOffset="1127" SampleCount="1"/>
<SampleSizeEntry Size="2581"/>
<ChunkEntry offset="17065364"/>
<TimeToSampleEntry SampleDelta="1024" SampleCount="6"/>
<SampleToChunkEntry FirstChunk="2525" SamplesPerChunk="19" SampleDescriptionIndex="1"/>
<SampleSizeEntry Size="301"/>
```

etc...

What I need to know is how to read and understand this data in order to map seconds, key-frames and bytes. For example, I want to be able to tell that second 100 maps keyframe 500 maps to byte 30520 (From the beginning of the .mp4 file).

Comment: I could start to explain how it works but that would take an hour of writing. So I rather ask you what you are trying to achieve and perhaps point you to tool/lib that already does what you want. What's your goal and what's your language (java? right?)?
If you just want extract raw frames you might want to look at my http://mp4parser.googlecode.com project

Comment: If you want a detailed information on samples, you can visit site http://www.onlinemp4parser.com/